# On radio button change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a set of 2 radio buttons that change the device orientation when changed.

The issue I am having is that when the I select the landscape radio button, it works, however when I reselect the portrait one, I get an alert Landscape and it remains the same.

Here is my try:

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<input type="radio" name="orientation" id="portrait" value="1" checked />
<label for="portrait">Portrait</label>

<input type="radio" name="orientation" id="landscape" value="2" />
<label for="landscape">Landscape Mode</label> 
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='orientation']").change(function() {
        if ($("input[name='orienation']:checked").val() == '1') {
            navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
            alert('portrait');
        }                
        else if ($("input[name='orienation']:checked").val() == '2') {
            navigator.screenOrientation.set('landscape');
            alert('landscape');
        }
    })
```

I am using jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Comment: You've misspelled "orientation" in your JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement should be more like:

```
if ($(this).val() == '1') {
  ...
}                
else if ($(this).val() == '2') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: While this is the ideal solution, it should also noted that the issue with the original code not working was due to $("input[name='orienation']:checked") having a typo in the input's name, causing the selector not to match the element.